# Spring Boot application with embedded Tomcat server way too slow

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, tomcat, centos

I have a **Spring Boot web application** that gets compiled into **WAR** files and executed on the production server.

The application works normally locally (*localhost*) and in our internal Linux server but when it comes to the production environment it's really really slow.

Before going further I have to specify that our entire application runs inside an Internal network (so the slowness may actually be related to the connection of the network but for security reasons I can't ping to test the actual speed of the connection so I just have to assume the problem comes from the application until I've tried basically everything).

I tried incrementing the heap size both in the pom.xml and server-side when I execute the .war files:

pom.xml for the backend:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <profiles>
                        <profile>prod</profile>
                        <profile>sit</profile>
                        <profile>preprod</profile>
                        <profile>uat</profile>
                    </profiles>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        -Xms8096m
                        -Xmx12144m
                    </jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

server commands to execute the WAR files:

```
java -Xmx12192 -Xms80192 <frontend>.war
java -Xmx12192 -Xms80192 <backend>.war
```

When I run TOP on the actual server I get these results:
[image]

So after trying to increase the heap size someone told me it may be a problem related to the queries but that wouldn't explain why those queries run much much faster on the local server (which also works with WAR files).

Is there anything more I can do before assuming the problem is related to the Internal network rather than the application itself?

The production server runs on CentOS 8 and I can't install packages because in the Internal Network I have no Internet access.

Comment: When the application runs locally, does it use the same amount of memory ?

Comment: Yes, the configuration is the same for both profiles and the production server even has more physical RAM assigned.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean configuration, but actual consumption. The JVM may be given a 12g heap, but would not necessarily use all of it, if it doesn't need it.

Comment: I just run the TOP command on the local server (I mean the Linux one with the WAR builds) and it gives back these results: https://imgur.com/a/JGjmutc

Apparently it is using a greater percentage of memory (but it has less allocated memory) but the CPU usage is the same, am I wrong?

Comment: On the contrary, I would say it uses less memory (I read 4,5g on this picture). Have you searched for a possible memoy leak, or something that would cause the garbage collector to activate to frequently ?

Comment: Not at all, would you mind sharing some resources I could use to start my research?

Comment: You should start with a profiler : https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers